# How to know which QLineEdit is focused?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qlineedit

I'm new in QT. Could someone help me with this?

I'm coding a widget application (with `QMainWindow`) with three `QLineEdits` widgets, I used `setText` to set a random text and connect the `timeout()` **signal** to a **slot**. When the timer "**interrupts**" I want to know in which `QLineEdit` the cursor is.

MainWindow constructor:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
timer = new QTimer(this);
timer -> start(1000); // 1 sec
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(FinishTimer()));
ui->lineEdit1->setText("Line1");
ui->lineEdit2->setText("Line2");
ui->lineEdit1->setFocus();
```

In finish timer function I want to move the cursor but first I need to know in which `QLineEdit` I am and the position of the cursor.

FinishTimer slot:

```
QString debug;
debug = this->focusWidget()->objectName(); //this is a debug line, it works fine 
// this line doesn't work
int position = this->focusWidget()->cursorPosition();
```

`cursorPosition` is a method of `QLineEdit`, the error is "`class QWidget has no member named 'cursorPosition'`". I hope you will understand me.

Comment: [`QWidget::focusWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusWidget) returns a `QWidget *`.  If you want to check if it's actually a `QLineEdit *` you need to downcast the returned value using [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) or [`qobject_cast`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast).

Comment: Thanks i use qobject_cast and it works. Thank you so much.

Comment: @arturo2307 if you found a valid solution for your problem you are encouraged to post an answer for your own question.

Comment: @arturo2307 Please consider adding your solution as an answer, instead of adding it to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

I used [`qobject_cast`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) and it works really well. Thanks

```
position=qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(this->focusWidget())->cursorPosition();
```